# Notification for my stores

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have 3 stores

1. acmemfarmsandkitchen.com - (main store)
2. seattle.acmemfarmsandkitchen.com
3. portland.acmemfarmsandkitchen.com

Using javascript / cookies, I want to know if it is possible to get a notification for each sub-domains so the customer will prevent ordering to the wrong store.

This cookie should store the location name and that way when the customer tries to sign into a different store they can get notified that they previously shopped on the selected store. but of course the notification will have an option if they want to continue shopping or proceed to the store that they previously ordered. let me know if this make sense. tnx

tia

Comment: this should be something the user controls, not the browser; it's reasonable that someone in Seattle might want to buy something from the Portland store for a friend, business trip, etc.

Comment: Totally unclear what you are wanting or trying to do

Comment: This cookie should store the location name and that way when the customer tries to sign into a different store they can get notified that they previously shopped on the selected store. but of course the notification will have an option if they want to continue shopping or proceed to the store that they previously ordered. let me know if this make sense. tnx